# How to remove (or meta noindex) at page /?comments_popup=

Tags: noindex

I noticed that my website has many page like this:

```
http://example.com/?comments_popup=837

http://example.com/?comments_popup={id of the page/post}
```

They are causing many duplicate/thin content pages. I'd like to remove, or at least place meta noindex to this. Which is the file to edit? I presume is in the core of wordpress.

Comment: Do you know what the [comments pop up link is](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_popup_link)?

Answer (score 0):

To add noindex while a request made with `comments_popup` query, try the following into your themes functions.php -

```
add_action('wp_head', 'wpse_wp_head');
function wpse_wp_head(){
    if( isset($_REQUEST['comments_popup']) && '' != $_REQUEST['comments_popup'] ){
        echo "<meta name='robots' content='noindex,follow' />\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, tried but not working..